# Which is the fastest way to solve inverse trigonometric numericals

Tags: trigonometry

Say I want to solve this $$\alpha = 2\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}})$$

What is the fastest way to solve these kind of trigonometric numericals if I know the values all trigonometric functions of $0$, $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$, $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$, $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

EDIT: I am not asking you to solve this problem but to give some ways to solve **these kind of** hard (for me) inverse trigonometric problems by using pen and paper. I have taken this as an example only.

Comment: If you tried to solve a large multiplication problem, you'd be happy to use a calculator.  For your class of equations, why not simply use a computer?  Incidentally, for your problem $a = 0.785398$.  Computers are *certainly* the fastest method, which is what you requested.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Calculators aren't allowed in exams

Comment: There was nothing mentioned about "exams" or "calculators" in the problem.

Comment: The example problem has got a nice exact value, $\dfrac{\pi}{8}$, so using numerical methods here is unreasonable.

Comment: @dbanet that's why I stated about the values I know.

Comment: What are you asking probably is: how to simplify radicals and inverse trigonometric expressions? Moreover, you actually kind of, I suppose, seek for a universal technique, which does not exist in this case.

Comment: @dbanet if not universal then maybe some tips and tricks which I can use more often?

Comment: These problems (which involve trigonometric functions, their inverses and radicals) are usually tackled using [known trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) and [techniques of nested radicals denesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Denesting_nested_radicals).

Comment: FYI: the nested radical in question is first in the list of examples on the linked Wikipedia page; your point of calculator usage prohibition on the exams seems irrelevant because, as I have said, numerical methods are not what you are asking about; Wolfram Language has got a function [``FullSimplify``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) which is [able to symbolically simplify many expressions of this type](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FullSimplify[2+ArcTan[Sqrt[3-2+Sqrt[2]]]]); my first comment should read $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ instead of $\dfrac{\pi}{8}$.

Comment: @dbanet I had no knowledge of denasting nested radicals. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

The radical can be removed,

$$\sqrt{3-2\sqrt2}=\sqrt2-1$$

but none of the angles you cite involve $\sqrt2$.

If we try to double the angle, we get

$$\frac{2(\sqrt2-1)}{1-(\sqrt2-1)^2}=\frac{2(\sqrt2-1)}{-2+2\sqrt2}=1.$$

Comment: it's not about this question. Its also about all other numerical of inverse trigonometry.

Comment: There are three lessons in this answer.

Comment: 1. denesting 2. look about what you know 3. use what you know. right?

Comment: 3. if you don't recognize the pattern, the answer is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\alpha}{2}=arctan\sqrt{3-2*\sqrt2}$$
$$\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}=\sqrt{3-2*\sqrt2}$$
$$\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}=\sqrt{(\sqrt2-1)^2}$$
$$\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}=\sqrt2-1$$

because:
$$\tan\alpha=\frac{2*\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}}{1-(\tan\frac{\alpha}{2})^2}$$
$$\tan\alpha=1$$
as a result:
$$\alpha=\frac{\pi}{4}$$